# Override operator of built-in object

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I would like to override the "+" operator of the "dict" class, in order to be able to merge two dictionaries easily.

Something like that:

```
def dict:
  def __add__(self,other):
    return dict(list(self.items())+list(other.items()))
```

Is it possible in general to override the operator of a built-in class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a word, no:

```
>>> dict.__add__ = lambda x, y: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'dict'
```

You need to subclass `dict` to add the operator:

```
import copy

class Dict(dict):

  def __add__(self, other):
    ret = copy.copy(self)
    ret.update(other)
    return ret

d1 = Dict({1: 2, 3: 4})
d2 = Dict({3: 10, 4: 20})
print(d1 + d2)
```

Personally, I wouldn't bother and would just have a free function for doing that.

Comment: don't forget to also subclass `__iadd__` if you want to things like `d1 += d2'...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Actually you don't need to override `__iadd__` for that to work. The only reason to do so would be to allow `+=` to operate in-place (`+` has to create a new dict for sanity).

Answer (score 3):

You can create subclass of dict (as @NPE said):

```
class sdict(dict):
    def __add__(self,other):
        return sdict(list(self.items())+list(other.items()))
```

---

### <strike>I am not sure, but you can try to modify some objects in `site.py`</strike>. Doesn't work

---

Why not to create **your own *Python Shell***?

Here is an example:

### **shell.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os

#Define some variables you may need

RED = "\033[31m"

STD = "\033[0m"

class sdict(dict):
    def __add__(self,other):
        return dict(list(self.items())+list(other.items()))

dict = sdict

sys.ps1 = RED + ">>> " + STD
del sdict # We don't need it here!


# OK. Now run our python shell!
print sys.version
print 'Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.'
os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT'] = 'True'
```

Comment: Your first suggestion doesn't work: `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'dict'`

Comment: What about dict = sdict?

Comment: @Basilevs, I wrote about it. You can do this in `site.py`

Comment: Literals still won't work: `dict = sdict; type({'a':1}) >>><type, 'dict'>`

Comment: @Vik2015: I had tried before ;) and it surprised me a little, given the fact that Python is __so flexible.__ I'm almost sure it's because this types are really defined in a C module. So you can instrocspect them much. I think with Ruby you can so, there is a +1 for Ruby this time (sadly):D

Comment: @PauloBu, check out my modified answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This might look like the following:

```
 class MyDict(dict):
     def __add__(self,other):
         return MyDict(list(self.items())+list(other.items()))
```