# Interpret Python v2.5 code using Python v3.x and C API (with respect to integer division)

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer-division, python-2.5, c-api

I have a  v2.5 Python code which I cannot control, as it is being exported from a third party software which supports Python v2.5.

I have Python v3.3 on my machine and I want, somehow, to emulate the v2.5
using the C API. My main concern is the integer division which differs between v2.x and v3.x.

For example I have the code below:

```
a=1
b=a/2
c=a/2.
```

I want somehow this to be interpreted (using the v3.x) as:

```
a=1
b=a//2
c=a/2.
```

Can I do something about that? Is there any way to interpret the code as if I had Python v2.5? I suppose that the 2to3 script does not work for my case, neither the six module.

I also found this question relative to mine:
[Python 2 and Python 3 dual development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372190/python-2-and-python-3-dual-development)

Thanks

Comment: You mean that `a//2` does not work? Python3-x [explicitly](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers) defines that as "integer division".

Comment: @usr2564301 no, he's saying that he wants his Python3 interpreter to parse `b = a/2` in a Python2 context, which is to say: `b = a//2`

Comment: @AdamSmith: if that is the case: well, for custom classes at least, Python allows redefinition of operators. I am too new to Python to know top of my head if that goes as well for built-in classes such as `integer` and (per OP's wishlist) `float`.

Comment: @AdamSmith Correct! that is what I am saying

Comment: ... [my question for old Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19404796) gets a resounding "no", and I have not read that Python-3.x had any significant change in this. So that seems to be the answer: no you cannot.

Comment: Port the third party library to python 3. Both python 2.5 and python 3.3 have reached support end of life years ago.

Comment: Or just run the Python 2.5 code as a subprocess in Python 2.5.

Comment: *"I have Python v3.3 on my machine"* go get 2.5 as well then. The package manager [**conda**](https://conda.io/docs/index.html) is pretty great about [treating python itself as a package](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python) so you can create separate environments for separate versions.

Comment: @HåkenLid I think this is the best solution. To run the 2.5 as a subprocess. So I need to have v2.5 as package to my machine as well...

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a bad idea—and you're going to have much more serious problems interpreting Python 2.5 code as Python 3, like every `except` statement being a syntax error, and strings being the wrong type (or, if you fix that, `s[i]` returning an int rather than a bytes), and so on.

---

The obvious thing to do here is to port the code to a Python that's still supported.

If that really is impossible for some reason, the simplest thing to do is probably to write a trivial Python 2.5 wrapper around the code you need to run, which takes its input via `sys.argv` and/or `sys.stdin` and returns results via `sys.exit` and/or `sys.stdout`.

Then, you just call it like this:

```
p = subprocess.run(['python2.5', 'mywrapper.py', *args], capture_output=True)
if p.retcode:
    raise Exception(p.stderr.decode('ascii'))
results = p.stdout.splitlines().decode('ascii')
```

---

But if you really want to do it, and this is really your only problem… this still isn't the *way* to do it.

You'd have to go below the level of the C API, into the internal type objects like [`struct PyFloat_Type`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L1910), access their `tp_as_number` structs, and copy their `nb_floordiv` functions to their `nb_truediv` slots. And even that may not change everything.

---

A much better solution is to build an import hook that transforms the AST before compiling it.

Writing an import hook is probably too big a topic to cover in a couple of paragraphs as a preface to an answer, so see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43571737/) for that part.

Now, as for what the import hook actually does, what you want to do is replace the `MyLoader.exec_module` method. Instead of this:

```
def exec_module(self, module):
    with open(self.filename) as f:
        data = f.read()

    # manipulate data some way...

    exec(data, vars(module))
```

You're going to do this:

```
def exec_module(self, module):
    with open(self.filename) as f:
        data = f.read()

    tree = ast.parse(data)

    # manipulate tree in some way

    code = compile(tree, self.filename, 'exec')
    exec(code, vars(module))
```

So, how do we "manipulate tree in some way"? By building a [`NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer).

Every `/` expression is a `BinOp` node, where the `op` is `Div` node with no attributes, and the `left` and `right` are the values to divide. If we want to change it into the same expression but with `//`, that's the same `BinOp`, but where the `op` is `FloorDiv`.

So, we can just visit `Div` nodes and turn them into `FloorDiv` nodes:

```
class DivTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Div(self, node):
        return ast.copy_location(ast.FloorDiv(), node)
```

And our "# manipulate tree in some way" becomes:

```
tree = DivTransformer().visit(tree)
```

---

If you want to choose between `floordiv` and `truediv` depending on whether the divisor is an integral literal, as your examples seem to imply, that's not much harder:

```
class DivTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Div):
            if isinstance(node.right, ast.Num) and isinstance(node.right.val, int):
                return ast.copy_location(ast.BinOp(
                    left=node.left,
                    op=ast.copy_location(ast.FloorDiv(), node.op),
                    right=node.right))
        return node
```

---

But I doubt that's what you actually want. In fact, what you actually want is probably pretty hard to define. You probably want something like:

- `floordiv` if both arguments, at runtime, are integral values
- `floordiv` if the argument that will end up in control of the `__*div__`/`__*rdiv__` (by exactly reproducing the rules used by the interpreter for that) is an integral value.
- … something else?

Anyway, the only way to do this is to replace the `BinOp` with a `Call` to a `mydiv` function, that you write and, e.g., stick in `builtins`. That function then does the type-switching and whatever else is needed to implement your rule, and then either `return a/b` or `return a//b`.

Comment: They want to treat `a/2.` as truediv instead of converting all division to floordiv, though.

Comment: @user2357112 I added a section to that effect. As stated, that isn't a well-defined requirement. And figuring out how to define it is actually the hard part. For example, do they really want `a/2` to be truediv even if `a` is a float?

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for the answer. Ι will further investigate it as I am new to Python. However, in order to answer to your question, I want, ideally, to do this: python3.interpret_like_python2x(code_v2x). I want to take the same results as those I would have obtained if I had used the python v2.x interpreter.

Comment: @tsahmatsis Is `code_v2x` source code? A function object? A module name? …? And, as I mentioned in the question: is there a reason that can't just be `subprocess.run(['python2.5', 'code_v2x.py', … some args …], …)`? Because that would be by far the easiest thing to do.

Comment: @abarnert code_v2x is source code that should be interpreted in the same way as Python v2.x does by using v3.x.

Comment: @abarnert  I think this is the best solution. To run the 2.5 as a subprocess. So I need to have v2.5 as package to my machine as well...