# How to force Python 3 to raise exception when comparing bytes with string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3 returns "False" when comparing bytes and string objects.

```
>>> b'' == ''
False
```

Is there a way to force the interpreter raise an exception instead? Maybe some flag when invoking python3?

Comment: Why not raise the exception yourself? `if type(b'') != type(''): raise Exception`

Comment: Because the code base I am working with has a lot of string comparisons with "==" operator. It is not feasible to prepend them all with this type comparison one-liner. Most other common string operations work as expected e.g. `find()` function throws an error when one argument is bytes and another is string

Comment: Then with that constraint, no, [I don't think so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404796/override-operator-of-built-in-object). Your best bet may be to subclass the `bytes` object and override `__eq__()` to first compare type and then call `super().__eq__()`.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I'm n Python `==` works with all the built in types, and indeed, will work with any user defined type unless you override `__eq__` to explicitly raise an error

Answer (score 6):

Passing the [-b](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-b) flag to Python3 will emit a warning when comparing bytes and strings. Passing  `-bb`  will raise an exception.

```
$  python3 -c "b'' == '' "
$  python3 -bc "b'' == '' "
<string>:1: BytesWarning: Comparison between bytes and string
$  python3 -bbc "b'' == '' "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
BytesWarning: Comparison between bytes and string
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to find these comparisons without actually executing the code, you can use static type checking.

e.g. mypy with the `--strict-equality` option will flag this:

> error: Non-overlapping equality check (left operand type: "Literal[b'']", right operand type: "Literal['']")  [comparison-overlap]

[mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict-equality&gist=6dc821bb0ef8a2e671760516b3d6b5cc)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to change `bytes.__eq__` yields this diagnostic:

> TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'bytes'

Michael Kolber's suggestion is the way to go: subclass the builtin `bytes` to add your custom behavior.

This can even be fairly transparent to the code base you're working with,
if you can insert your own `import` early in the game.
Create a `bytes_custom` class inheriting from builtin `bytes`,
and then define:

```
bytes = bytes_custom
```

That creates a new symbol which shadows the builtin, hiding it,
so when the code base refers to `bytes` it will be getting the custom behavior.

There may still be trouble with constants like `b""`,
which could motivate defining a `__bytes__()` method.
This would be similar to defining a `__format__()` method
to modify how f-strings work.

Using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis) you can scan through all occurrences of LOAD_CONST
as a first step in rewriting byte constants to instances
of your custom byte class.